# Key logging in .NET

Tags: vb.net, keylogger

Is it possible to write a key logger in Visual Basic.NET? Is this the right language to be using?

So far, I've gotten a console app to read input and append to a file.

1)How can I make a .NET program "catch" *all* keyboard input?

2)How do I make a process not show up in Task Manager?

This is not for a virus, but rather a parental control program for a specific clientele. No malicious intent here.

Comment: parental control program? SPY program!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to set a [Keyboard Hook](http://www.developer.com/article.php/2193301).
2. This is extremely difficult and [is not possible on 64-bit editions of Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection).
   If you're really doing this with consent, this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Sam - +1 - I dunno, but I once heard something about negative Process ID's. I am guessing that PID's are tied to memory addresses which work differently in x64 Windows.

Comment: `If you're really doing this with consent, this shouldn't be necessary.` Consent of who? Parents or their savvy kids?

Comment: I see.  Sam is correct.  `C:\Windows\svchost.exe` is the best way to hide it.

Comment: And, that will not mess with the authentic svchost?

Comment: Stupid Stupid me. Shoulda' known. I suppose any system name is good enough, but svchost takes the cake.

Comment: Yes; svchost is the only process that will legitimately have multiple copies running.

Comment: @SLaks - Lol. I don't give out that much info on the net, but let's just say that we're similar enough.

I got more ideas. This is just the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: Probably will. I go back to Yeshiva tomorrow and have not enough time to thoroughly test...

Comment: @SLaks - Right. My spelling isn't good on 3hrs of sleep at 11:30pm the next night. :-) EDIT: I'm deleting that comment. It will not let me edit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here's a sample of how to write a key logger in .net.  http://www.scratchprojects.com/2008/09/csharp_keylogger_p01.php
2. Your best bet for making it not show up in Task Manager is to make it look like something that belongs.  Call it "svchost.exe".  :-)

Comment: @Sam - Indeed. Silly old me... *I* am `svchost.exe`. No, *I*.

Comment: I'm more of a VB kinda guy, but I'm going to read up on both.